# Optional as a return type

Tags: java, interface, option-type

I'm having trouble implementing a given interface and I don't really understand the second method.

```
/**
 * Saves the given student. If the given student is already present in the
 * repository then the method will act as an update operation.
 *
 * @param student must not be {@literal null}
 * @return the saved student; will never be {@literal null}
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException in case the given {@literal student} is {@literal null}.
 */
Student save(Student student);

/**
 * Retrieves a student by its id.
 *
 * @param id the unique student identifier
 * @return the student with the given id or {@literal Optional#empty()} if none found.
 */
Optional<Student> findById(int id);

/**
 * Deletes the student with the given id.
 *
 * @param id id the unique student identifier
 */
public void deleteById(int id);
```

This is what I've done so far

```
public class StudentCrudRepositoryImplementation implements StudentCrudRepository {
    private List<Student> studentsList;

    public StudentCrudRepositoryImplementation() {
        studentsList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Student save(Student student) {
        if (student == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
       //check if the given student has the same id with an already existing one, if yes update it
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Student> findById(int id) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (Student s : studentsList) {
            if (s.getId() == id) {
                found = true;
                return
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }
```

The Optional return type puts me in difficulty. I would really appreciate if someone gave ma an implementation for findById and save methods!

Comment: `if (s.getId() == id) { return Optional.of(s); }`

Comment: Thank you, it is the first time I use optional so I quite know nothing about its methods!

Answer (score 2):

Here, you don't need `found` just return the student when you find it

```
public Optional<Student> findById(int id) {
    for (Student s : studentsList) {
        if (s.getId() == id) {
            return Optional.of(s);
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Or if you like lambda:

```
public Optional<Student> findById(int id) {
    return studentsList.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getId() == id)
        .findFirst();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! As it can be seen from the postcondition in the interface, Optional.empty() must be returned in case of failure, so there is no need for lambdas. Thow, nice you gave me this lambda solution too!

Comment: @AlexandraDediu The findFirst() method will return Optional.empty() if no student is found (It's just hidden in the method)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already on Java-8, you can also make use of `Stream`s in the implementation such as:

```
public Optional<Student> findById(int id) {
    return studentsList.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getId() == id)
            .findAny(); // returns 'Optional<Student>'
}
```